# google analytics tracking link clicks

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

I was wondering how would i go about adding a simple tracking to a certain link on a site I am developing for a client

I am using google analytics for tracking the source of the incoming traffic and after the visitor has entered the site he supposed to click on a link, I an interested in knowing how many clicks I got from every source.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for "Campaigns". There's an extensive article about it here: http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1239239

You can use the "[URL Builder](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1033867)" tool to create a URL for a specific link (on an external site, presumably) by giving a name to your campaign and other details. The parameters are utm_source, utm_medium, and utm_campaign in particular.

I'll mention that Analytics will already tell you (without any modification to the link) what referring page sent a visitor, so you can tell what page a visitor was viewing before arriving at your site. All this is found under "Traffic Sources" in the Analytics reporting interface. The utility of campaigns is if either (a) you'll be scattering links in ads on many different websites, and it's the ***ad*** rather than the ***page*** that you want to track, or (b) there may be multiple links to your site on the same page and you want to know which one the visitor clicked.